# Why variable order of JSON text is different than struct after it is converted from struct to JSON Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, type-conversion

We wanted to create certain JSON format with swift 5 and we succeed with a weird bug.

Here is the swift code

```
 struct Coordinates: Codable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
    var width: Int
    var height: Int
   }


struct Label: Codable {
    var label: String = ""
    var coordinates = Coordinates(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}


struct Annotations: Codable {
    var image = ""
    var annotations :[Label] = [] 
}

var annotations:[Annotations] = []
var label: [Label] = []




func constract(x: CGFloat,
               y: CGFloat,
               w: CGFloat,
               h: CGFloat,
               image: String,
               labell: String,
               imageFileName:String) {
    
    
    
 
    let xx = Int(x)
    let yy = Int(y)
    let ww = Int(w)
    let hh = Int(h)
 

   let coorData = Coordinates(x: xx, y: yy, width: ww, height: hh)

   label.append(Label(label: labell, coordinates: coorData))

   annotations.append(Annotations(image: imageFileName, annotations: label) )

    
   let encoder = JSONEncoder()

   encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    
    
    do {
        

    let data = try encoder.encode(annotations)
     
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)


    } catch {
        print("JSONEncoder error")
    }
}
```

This is the result;

```
 [
  {
    "image" : "0.png",
    "annotations" : [
     {
      "label" : "myImage",
      "coordinates" : {
        "y" : 859,
        "x" : 459,
        "width" : 79,
        "height" : 19
       }
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

Why is the y and x variable placement is not correct ?  Is this a bug ? Or Am I missing something ?

Comment: You said "encoder.encode(annotations)", so you encode Annotations array. What is strange?

Comment: x should come before y

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. The order is irrelevant.

Comment: Where is the dictionary ? We have struct and JSON

Comment: `{ ... }` is a dictionary. The struct becomes a dictionary

Comment: So you say JSON format is a dictionary. I dont know at all. If it is true do you think when we supply the result Create ML it is going to get it correctly. I mean it does not care the order but tags.

Comment: You can try encoder.outputFormatting = [.sortedKeys] , but it doesn't guarantee the definition order anyway.

Comment: I don't say that. I said the struct `Coordinates` becomes a JSON dictionary where the order of the keys is irrelevant.

Comment: @Hope It's the way JSONEncoder works, converts property set to a dictionary.

Comment: I search a bit but could not find anything about Create ML behavior if values are not ordered. Training takes long time with a lot of values I did not want to make try and error approach

Comment: It's a basic behavior and not related to Create ML. Dictionary values are retrieved by **key**, unlike arrays where the values are retrieved by **index**.

Comment: Yes I understood that. Create ML should be taking values according to value names as well because it is excepting JSON but I wanted to be sure. I am not erasing question because It took some time to create JSON that way with Swift maybe somebody can benefit.